# Iframe trigger function issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe

using iframe inside Angular component, in iframe there is list of users, is there any way when i click on user it will trigger a function, that function will be inside component .ts file.

Comment: Do not quote my words but iframes are sandboxed for security reason, unless they are from the same domain, you can't interact with the iframe's content.

Answer (score 0):

Communication between an iframe and parent document is not possible for cross-origin 
In case same origin you can send/broadcast the message and receive in same window object. from the receiver message you can call your custom message.

resources.

```
Template :
    <iframe src="http://javascript.info" name="example">

Component : 
    let win = window.frames.example;

    win.postMessage("message", "http://example.com");
```

Receive the broadcaster message :

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  if (event.origin != 'http://javascript.info') {
    // something from an unknown domain, let's ignore it
    return;
  }

  alert( "received: " + event.data );
});
```